# Windows Media Player in C++ Application

Tags: c++, windows, windows-media-player

I am writing small application which can video in Windows Media Player.I need to resize it on full screen, but i cannot do it like that:

```
int main(void)
{
    char szPath[] = "C:\\WindowsApi\\WindowsApi\\GandalfSax.wmv";//Path to video

    HINSTANCE hRet = ShellExecute(
        NULL, 
        "open",       
        szPath,      
        NULL,        
        NULL,        
        SW_SHOW|SW_MAXIMIZE);//Or SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED     
    return 0;
}
```

But this approach do not work. I think that Windows Player do not handle 
this flag. I do not know how can i do it in diffrent way.
(The Microsoft Documentation suggest to use ATL, but i use Express version).

Comment: The `SW_*` flags do not combine bitwise: you can only pick one. `SW_MAXIMIZE` and `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` are synonyms; they both have the integer value 3. Aside from that, "maximized" does not mean quite the same thing as "full screen". If you want to launch WMP full-screen, then you should be able to use the `/fullscreen` switch on the command line. (At least, I think it used to have that option. Not sure if the current version supports it.)

Comment: Where should i pass "/fullscreen"?(as 4th parameter?)

Comment: You can't pass parameters when opening a document file. You'd have to change the path to open the media player executable, passing both the switch and the path to the file to open as arguments. Not sure if this will work; check on the command line first.

Comment: Thanks man. It has worked.